# Rails 7 + Hotwire/Turbo: Is it possible to specify the location of a turbo_stream.erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

#### Scenario

Take for example the following code:

```rb
class AwesomeController < ApplicationController
  
  ...
  
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.turbo_stream
    end
  end
  
  ...
  
end
```

As I understand it, the default behavior of `format.turbo_stream` is render a `*.turbo_stream.erb` file with the same name of the action, in the associated `views` subdirectory.

So in this case, the following file would be rendered: `app/views/awesome/update.turbo_stream.erb`.

#### Question

I want to specify a different file, in a different location (e.g., `app/views/somewhere_else/update.turbo_stream.erb`).
Is this possible?

##### Self-Help

- Where can I find the documentation on `format.turbo_stream`?
- I'm also particularly interested in reading about the `turbo_stream` option for `render` (e.g., `render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(...)`. Where can I find this documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream { render "path-to-file" }
end
```

Make sure to put the direct path to the file. So for example if I have a file structure like:

/views/posts/custom_turbo_streams/create.turbo_stream.erb

You'll have:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream { render "posts/custom_turbo_streams/create" }
end
```